# Verifying policy id from pub key

Tags: policy, mint

Is there any way to verify a policy against a policy.vkey (or even policy.skey in my case).

Thing is we would prefer to not store on external backend all of our NFT policies.

Use case to fill would be: "I receive an NFT (a long time after his mint) and I really want to verify that I am the issuer".

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Use case to fill would be: "I receive an NFT (a long time after his mint) and I really want to verify that I am the issuer".

This is not a realistic use case. If the policy ID listed when you query a Cardano wallet matches the string of a policy ID that you minted in the past, then it is verified. There's no way to send someone a token that has a policy ID without being signed by your skey, so there would be no possible way to spoof it, and therefore no need to 'verify' it using a key in the future.

EDIT: In re-reading your post, maybe I am misunderstanding.. Are you saying you'd prefer to not keep a record of the policy ID strings you've minted in the past? It seems like just creating a text file that stores all of your policy IDs would be the same effort as keeping the .vkey or .skey's from past policies..

Comment: Yes, your Edit is correct. we do not want to keep track of any policy ID we generated. In our mind, if our pub key was public anyone could verify the policy on their own without us involved. It is more for others than us. You know we had in mind the very similar way people are verifying today jwt with jwks/well-known open to anyone (oauth2). Anyway you seem to confirm that there is no way unfortunately to avoid storing them which is a bit sad. Thanks.